# Replacing Swiper pagination with text from html

Tags: javascript, html, pagination, swiper.js

Am having a hard time with my swiper pagination, i changed my pagination to text, the click event works well but the active class does not cycle through other pagination and auto play does not work too. but if i replace it with only (index + 1) every thing works well. Any help is appreciated.

[image: image of what am doing]

```
<div class="swiper-pagination swiper-pagination-clickable swiper-pagination-
bullets" style="background: #fff">
    <div class="swiper-pagination-bullet swiper-pagination-bullet-active">
     <div class="">1</div>
     hello there you are
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-pagination-bullet">active not</div>
    <div class="swiper-pagination-bullet">active not</div>
    <div class="swiper-pagination-bullet ">active not</div>
</div>

var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper1',{
autoplay: {
    delay: 1000,
    disableOnInteraction: true,
  },
disableDraggable: true,
pagination: {
    el: '.swiper-pagination',
    clickable: true,
    renderBullet: function (index, className) {
      return '<div class="' + className + '">' + (text) + (index + 1) + 
     '</div>';

    },
  },
loop: true
});
```

Comment: Where did you get the `(text)`?

Comment: from the html @HarleyDelaCruz

Comment: Check my answer

Comment: is there any one i can customize  it to look like the one in (http://www.crestoptions.com) @HarleyDelaCruz

Answer (score 2):

It wont work because it'll throw a `ReferenceError: text is not defined`.
Where did it came from?

if you're trying to add custom text inside the bullets you can try:

```
let labels = ['label1', 'label2', 'label3'];
```

and on your renderBullet function you can do:

```
renderBullet: function (index, className) {
  return '<div class="' + className + '">' + (labels[index]) + (index + 1) + 
 '</div>';

},
```

Here's a working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fsvsdbex/)

Comment: yeah that's nice but i would like to customize it more, example of what am trying to do is this website (http://www.crestoptions.com) @Harley Dela Cruz